# Efficiently replacing text in a file between two lines matching a pattern

Tags: python, sed

I want to edit a very long file in python after the first ocurrence of a heading. The file looks something like this:

```
*First Heading
line1
line2
line3
line4
*Second Heading
line1
line2
line3
line4
*Third Heading 
line1
line2
line3
...
...
more headings and many more lines
```

I want to replace (for example) the line2 of the Second Heading, for something like this:

```
someNewtext line2
```

I can do this very efficiently with sed using something like this:

```
sed -e -i '/\*Second\ Heading/,/\*Third\ Heading/s/line2/someNewText\ line2/' file.txt
```

Can I do something similar in Python in an efficient manner?

Comment: python or efficient you have to choose one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we gonna port the `sed` command to `python`, it will look something like:

```
import re
import fileinput

state = 0
for line in fileinput.input('file.txt', inplace=True, backup='.bak'):
    line = line.rstrip('\r\n')
    if state == 1:
        line = re.sub('line2', 'someNewText line2', line)
    if line.startswith('*Second Heading'):
        state = 1
    elif line.startswith('*Third Heading'):
        state = 0
    print line
fileinput.close()
```

It will be efficient in execution time but may not be as efficient
in programming as `sed` or `Perl`. Sigh.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html), you can just use sed as before.

```
subprocess.run("sed -e -i '/\*Second\ Heading/,/\*Third\ Heading/s/line2/someNewText\ line2/' file.txt")
```